# When using TalkBack, what is the preferred way to alert the user when the contents of a TextView have changed?

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I have an unlock screen where the user is prompted to enter a four digit pin. If the user enters their pin incorrectly, a previously invisible `TextView` is shown with an error message. At this point it would be useful for TalkBack to read the contents of the error message out loud.

Through some experimentation, I realized I could set `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` on the view and programmatically call [`View#requestFocus()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestFocus%28%29). This works the first time, but fails on subsequent errors since the view already has focus. Also it seems like a bad idea in general to override the current view focus.

I then tried invoking [`View#announceForAccessibility(java.lang.CharSequence)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#announceForAccessibility%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) when the error message is displayed. Apparently this method will *silently fail* if the view is not currently visible. No problem and otherwise it works perfectly. However, it's only available in API level 16+ (Jelly Bean) which really limits it's usefulness. There has to be a better solution since TalkBack supports API level 7+.

I've watched both the 2011 and 2012 Google I/O sessions on accessibility, but neither seem to cover this basic use case. What's the best way to do this?

**Edit 1:** TLDR; Is there a way to *force* TalkBack to read some text out loud prior to the introduction of `View#announceForAccessibility(java.lang.CharSequence)` in Jelly Bean?

Comment: How are they entering the PIN? If via an `EditText`, have you considered using `setError()` instead of a separate `TextView`? My guess is that `setError()` will be tied into the a11y framework already.

Comment: The layout contains a custom soft keypad that is made up of `Button` views 0-9 that are used to provide input. The digits are not displayed in an `EditText`, so unfortunately `setError()` is not an option. Good idea though. The layout is very similar to the Google Wallet unlock screen layout if that's helpful.

Comment: for the record, setError won't yield an announcement of the error text via TalkBack unless the user specifically presses on it (Explore by Touch). The ErrorPopup won't be included in the screens list of views, so navigating by swiping won't reach it. This means the possibly blind user must know that the ErrorPopup exists and where it is displayed or stumble upon it - which is far from reasonable UX.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to use `View.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED)` on your `TextView` to trigger TalkBack in the same way that `View.requestFocus()` would. Since it only triggers the event, and doesn't actually focus the View, it shouldn't crash after the first time.

Comment: I just confirmed that this does indeed work in Gingerbread. Thanks for the concise solution!

Comment: Do you have any idea how can we do the same in jetpack compose?

Answer (score 9):

I was using the accepted answer, which works well. However, I didn't like the misleading sound when accessibility focus was set on the text view - the same sound as when input focus is given to an EditField by double-tapping (a sort of drawer-open sound), because the input focus had not actually moved from the EditText with inputfocus (eg with cursor).

So I tried:

```
m_textView.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED);`
```

and interestingly it works - the label is read, without moving any focus or giving any other sound.

Answer (score 2):

OK, if you are using L or later the better answer is to use:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAccessibilityLiveRegion(int)

This will do all the work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to, when TalkBack is activated, additionally show a Toast message with the error text. This is also being read out aloud.

Comment: I confirm this solution as well, that will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Recommended way is to use the below code after textview change.

```
textview.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_ANNOUNCEMENT);
```

It will read the contents without focusing on it.