# How do I implement audio prompts for accessibility?

Tags: android, accessibility

I'm trying to make my application (a calculator) accessible in TalkBack and Explore By Touch modes.

Setting it up so that all of the buttons are accessible was easy, just a matter of setting the android:contentDescription attribute.

But how do I get the app to simply announce things? E.g. if the user does "2 + 2 =", I want the voice to say "4". Now, the user could hear the result by selecting the TextView holding the answer, but I think the app would be a lot more useable if it just announced the result.

I also want to announce the annunciator, e.g. "Error: divide by zero"

Alternative way to phrase my question: How do I trigger a talkback event on a widget?

Comment: Not a mobile dev, so I can't give exact answers, but found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234607/android-set-focus-to-a-button-widget-programmatically-oncreate-of-the-activity. My thought is if `=` is pressed go to the TextView where the calculation is

Comment: Seems that this is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13205498/, but is there a way to announce an arbitrary string?

Comment: Set the TextView containing the error text to be a [live region](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:accessibilityLiveRegion).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, that seems to be new in API 19 and I'm trying to support back to API 4.