# Android TalkBack and fragment stack

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, accessibility, talkback

For an application that I work on, I need to implement accessibility. Everything works fine except for one screen where I have to fragments added to my activity. Basically, the fragment that is above is a dial keyboard to enter a passcode. This fragment is added with a fragmentTransaction.

The thing is that the talkback focus is set on the elements of the underneath fragment.

Do you know if there is a way to set the talkback focus on the dial fragment ? I just want to "disable" the fragment underneath to get focus

Thanks,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

UPDATE

I figured out the solution. you can disable the accessibility of the first fragment before you do the fragment transaction.

```
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment, null, false);

rootView.setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO_HIDE_DESCENDANTS);
```

and now you commit your fragment transaction. Second fragment won't leak the focus to first fragment.

Don't forget to enable the accessibility of first fragment in case you're coming back to the first fragment.

```
if(rootView != null) {
    rootView.setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_YES);
}
```

Comment: This works fine but child views not getting focus on first fragment on next swipe. Any solution?

Comment: @fargath you have to enable the accessibility of first fragment using the second code example

Comment: This solution works great. If you are using databinding, then onCreateView use:

MyFragmentLayoutBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.my_fragment_layout, container, false);
binding.getRoot.setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO_HIDE_DESCENDANTS);

Answer (score 3):

Are you using fragmentTransaction.add?

If so you sould use fragmentTransaction.replace!

Add function also did problems with clicking the below fragment views.

So please, use replace.

Comment: getting this issue even with replace

Answer (score 2):

Your problem isn't "sending" focus to the correct place.  Forcing focus around to different places is generally a bad idea, and inaccessible.  Your problem is that you have elements on the screen that aren't visible, but are being focused by TalkBack.  What you want to do is hide these elements from TalkBack.  Actually, you probably want to remove them completely, but let's assume that they need to be on the screen.  What you can do is hide them from the accessibility service:

```
rootViewOfFragment.setImportantForAccessibility(IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO_HIDE_DESCENDANTS);
```

This will hide those views from TalkBack.  This is a better solution than forcing focus to a specific element, as this is generally an accessibility violation under WCag 2.0.  Though if the elements on screen are not completely hidden by your "top" fragment, this is also a violation, and you should actually just leave things be.

Comment: This does not work for me. Did anyone come up with a solution for this?

Comment: Tried this also and it isn't working. Am going to keep trying to fix this and see if I can find something that works.

Comment: Were the people in comments able to find the solution for same?

Answer (score 0):

Look at method View.`sendAccessibilityEvent`(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED). `sendAccessibilityEvent` changes focus from Talkback. I don't know much about Talkback, pls read a link on SO @ [When using TalkBack, what is the preferred way to alert the user when the contents of a TextView have changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13205498/when-using-talkback-what-is-the-preferred-way-to-alert-the-user-when-the-conten?rq=1).

Good luck...

Comment: Forcing accessibility focus around is a bad idea.  A: it's an accessibility violation under WCag 2.0.  B: what if the user swypes back?  They'll still end up focusing those things that he doesn't want focused.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can call requestAccessibilityFocus() when the second fragment resumes

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    yourView.requestAccessibilityFocus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
view.setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_YES);`
view.performAccessibilityAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS, null);
```

inside `onResume`

and adding

```
view.setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO_HIDE_DESCENDANTS);
```

inside `onPause` works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using replace fragment over add fragment is IMO a best answer, see here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21684520/3540391