# Accessibility focus remains on button on previous fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, accessibility

I have a bare bones test app with two fragments. The first fragment has a button that adds the second fragment. With TalkBack turned on, I tap the button on the first fragment to select it and it gets a green outline. Then, I double tap it and it opens the second fragment, but the green outline from the button on the first fragment is still there. And, because the button on the first fragment still has focus, I can't swipe to move the focus to anything on the second fragment.

Comment: You got solution for this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android TalkBack and fragment stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30225636/android-talkback-and-fragment-stack)