# Android Accessibility always gets the content of previous page in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, accessibility

I'm using Accessibility to read the content in ViewPager, in the first page, everything is alright, Accessibility is reading the content of current page, But when I turn to next page, Accessibility still reading the the content of previous page.

> For example:

Page1 -> TextView -> content1

Page2 -> TextView -> content2

Page3 -> TextView -> content3

Accessibility reads content1 when current page is Page1, then turn to Page2, Accessibility reads content1,Accessibility reads content2, this is so werid
reading code is like this:

```
 List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> nodeInfoList = accessibilityNodeInfo.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId(id);
    if (nodeInfoList != null && !nodeInfoList.isEmpty()) {
        for (AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo : nodeInfoList) {
            if (nodeInfo != null) {
                return nodeInfo.text;
            }
        }
    }
```

Any body help me?

Comment: Could you provide more information? For example full code of Activity and XML with view?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android TalkBack and fragment stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30225636/android-talkback-and-fragment-stack)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, sorry, the code is a little complicated,  wait a minute please

Comment: thanks isaaaaame, i'll try this solution

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with ViewPager, when manually dragged to a next page, TalkBack was OK, but when fake dragged by tapping on a button which had a fake drag code, then TalkBack on the ViewPager read position from the page before current page. So I turned off TalkBack on a fake drag and created new TalkBack event:

```
    animator.addListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener {
        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?) {
            isFakeDrag = true
            viewPager.importantForAccessibility = View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO
            viewPager.beginFakeDrag()
        }
        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
            viewPager.endFakeDrag()
            viewPager.importantForAccessibility = View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_YES
            isFakeDrag = false
        }
        override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator?) { /* Ignored */ }
        override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator?) { /* Ignored */ }
    })
```

and

```
viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback( object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        override fun onPageScrolled(
            position: Int,
            positionOffset: Float,
            positionOffsetPixels: Int
        ) {
            //some code
        }

        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
            super.onPageSelected(position)
            if(isFakeDrag) {
                val event = AccessibilityEvent.obtain()
                event.eventType = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_ANNOUNCEMENT
                val positionString = //create a string to be announced by TalkBack
                positionString.also { event.text.add(it) }
                val accessibilityManager = requireContext().getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE) as AccessibilityManager
                accessibilityManager.sendAccessibilityEvent(event)
            }
        }
    })
```